# Finding the 2017th power of a nondiagonalizable matrix

Tags: matrices

[Matrix image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XtPw.png)

The eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the matrix are as follows: https://matrixcalc.org/en/vectors.html#eigenvectors%28%7B%7B110,55,-164%7D,%7B42,21,-62%7D,%7B88,44,-131%7D%7D%29.

This matrix cannot be diagonalized since the eigenvectors are not linearly independent. How can I find the 2017th power in this case?

Comment: When a $3\times 3$ matrix has three _distinct_ eigenvalues, it _can_ be diagonalized, and its eigenvectors will be linearly independent.

Comment: Did you try finding the 3rd power of this matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

By *Hamilton-Cayley*, $A^3=A$. Deduce by an easy induction that, if $n>0$, $A^n$ depends only on $n$ being even or odd.